# Athena (Trino SQL) parsing JSON document using fields (dot notation)

Tags: json, format, amazon-athena, json-deserialization, trino

Athena (Trino SQL) parsing JSON document (table column called document 1 in Athena) using fields (dot notation)

If the underlying json (table column called document 1 in Athena) is in the form of `{a={b ...`
I can parse it in Athena (Trino SQL) using

```
document1.a.b
```

However, if the JSON contains  `{a={"text":  value1 ...`

the quote marks will **not** parse correctly.

Is there a way to do JSON parsing of a 'field' with quotes?

If not, is there an elegant way of parsing the "text" and obtain the string in value 1?  [Please see my comment below].

I **cannot** change the quotes in the json and its Athena "table" so I would need something that works in Trino SQL syntax.

The error message is in the form of:  `SQL Error [100071] [HY000]: [Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. SYNTAX_ERROR:  Expression [redacted] is not of type ROW`

*NOTE:*  This is *not* a duplicate of [Oracle Dot Notation Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570987/oracle-12c-json-query-issue-with-dot-notation-and-double-quotes)

Comment: One can cast( retrieved as varchar) and then apply standard Trino operators such as substring, position, etc.  The syntax gets very long, but it can work, if one has enough patience to see it through.  If someone has an answer that is more descriptive than this comment, please post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot notation works only for columns types as `struct<…>`. You can do that for JSON data, but judging from the error and your description this seems not to be the case. I assume your column is of type `string`.

If you have JSON data in a `string` column you can use [JSON](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/json.html) functions to parse and extract parts of them with JSONPath.

Comment: NOTE:  In Trino, the type is varchar, and for parsing, apparently one has to cast whatever is there into a varchar.   See also my comment on the question (if interested).

Comment: Athena is weird in that DDL is run through Hive, which uses names like "string" and "struct", and DML is run through Presto/Trino, where the corresponding types are called "varchar" and "row".